# LoadRunner (VUgen) does not invoke FireFox for recording

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

LoadRunner 12.53 (Vugen) doesn't invoke FireFox v52 during recording web browser. After I start Recording, I find firefox in windows process but it doesnt show up, it just stays in the process. But I can easily opens it up if I stop recording. I have no problem with chrome but something is preventing Firefox from showing up.

Comment: Does this happen after restarting your computer ?

Comment: Also - did you upgrade Firefox on this machine ?

Comment: I m using Web (http/html) protocol for recording, does it support firefox 52 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Cause:

The problem is that you upgraded FireFox on your machine to version 52. This version **is not supported** by LoadRunner TruClient.

When using TruClient - You should **never** upgrade FireFox on the that machine.

From HP official site:

> Version 12.53 release notes:
>
> Changes to browser version support:
>
> Chromium 46
>
> Firefox 40.0.3
>
> Internet Explorer 10 and 11 (Internet Explorer 9 is no longer supported)

---

### The solution:

1. Remove Firefox.
2. Remove LoadRunner.
3. Reboot your machine.
4. Reinstall LoadRunner.

---

### Not using Truclient protocol?

If you are trying to record an HTTP protocol, recording via FireFox is unrecommended. Record your script using Google Chrome or Internet Explorer.

When recording HTTP, you can use any browser. It makes no difference whatsoever. When replaying, you can set the User-Agent string under run-time settings or choose FireFox as the replay browser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, I m using Web (http/html) protocol , I m not using truClient web protocol, which works well.

Comment: You are trying to record HTTP with Firefox ?

Comment: I do not recommend recording HTTP with Firefox. For version 12.5 use only Chrome or Internet Explorer.

Comment: ohhh is it so that I can record with any browser that works and then run/replay (browser emulation) with any browser ? How do I confirm that my AUT works well in firefox then?

Comment: When recording HTTP, you can use any browser. It makes no difference whatsoever. When **replaying**, you can set the User-Agent string under run-time settings or choose FireFox as the replay browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137918/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-tanvir).

Comment: do u know why IE always gives me Res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm# Error ( though a bit off topic)